# Get all html nodes in a text

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have some texts (not HTML document) which have just `a` tags between other words, like this (this example has two `a` nodes):

```
<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://loremipsum.net/">http://loremipsum.net/</a>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://loremipsum.net/">http://loremipsum.net/</a> sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
```

I want to replace all of these tags with word `"link"`. `node` in this code:

```
var node = HtmlNode.CreateNode(text);
var links = node.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
```

just refers to the first link, but I want all links inside text. How can I find them? thanks.

Comment: hi @paqogomez, as I said, node just returns first link. in his answer, he suppose it is an html document, but it is a text so the result is not what I need. this question is the next step :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all links from document, then replace their inner html:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(text);

foreach (var link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a")) 
    link.InnerHtml = "link";

string result = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

Result is

```
<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://loremipsum.net/">link</a> 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, <a rel="nofollow" 
target="_blank" href="http://loremipsum.net/">link</a> sed diam nonummy nibh 
euismod  tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sergey. you saved my ass! (it will throw null exception if it hadn't any link, but no problem)

Comment: @user3293835 you are right - I forgot that HtmlAgilityPack returns `null` instead of empty node collection. Just save selected nodes to local variable like `links` and verify if its not null before enumeration